# Mover quadrado com mouse somente no vetor X ou Y

Tags: c++, qt

Estou aprendendo sobre o `QgraphicsScene`, `QgraphicsItem` estou tentando mover dois quadrados com o mouse na janela, porém movendo só no vetor X ou só no vetor Y, mas que eles se movam somente em um vetor por vez como se estivessem amarrados para se moverem somente na horizontal ou vertical, conforme arrasto o mouse.

Comment: Como exatamente você está fazendo a movimentação? Mostre a parte relevante do seu código.

Answer (score 3):

Se puder, poste um código atual com arrasto tradicional em todas as direçoes, que mostro como aplicar essa logica quando tiver um tempinho.

Por ora, segue a lógica em código "agnóstico":

Ao clicar no mouse:

```
xOrigemObjeto = xAtualObjeto;
yOrigemObjeto = yAtualObjeto;
xOrigemMouse = xMouse;
yOrigemMouse = yMouse;
```

Durante o arrasto (no signal do movimento do mouse):

```
deltaX = xOrigemMouse - xMouse;
deltaY = yOrigemMouse - yMouse;

if( abs( deltaX ) > abs( deltaY ) ) {
    xAtualObjeto = xOrigemObjeto + deltaX;
    yAtualObjeto = yOrigemObjeto;
} else {
    xAtualObjeto = xOrigemObjeto;
    yAtualObjeto = yOrigemObjeto + deltaY;
}
```

O único cuidado é atualizar a origem do objeto somente após o usuário soltar o mouse.

Basicamente o que estamos fazendo aqui é considerar se o mouse andou mais no X ou no Y, e alterar só uma das posições, "travando" a outra.